# One to many relationship in eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm following the information here:

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#one-to-many

I have an assets and sizes table.

An asset has many sizes.

So in my asset model I have:

```
class Asset extends Eloquent {

    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('sizes');
    }

}
```

But when I do:

```
Asset::find(1)->sizes;
```

I get:

```
Class 'sizes' not found
```

Where am I going wrong?

Migrations are:

```
Schema::create('assets', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
    });

    Schema::create('sizes', function($table){
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('asset_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('asset_id')->references('id')->on('assets');
        $table->string('width');
    });
```

My classes are also namespaced:

In my controller:

```
<?php namespace BarkCorp\BarkApp\Lib;
use BarkCorp\BarkApp\Asset;
```

then later:

```
Asset::find(1)->sizes;
```

My models:

Asset:

```
<?php namespace BarkCorp\BarkApp;

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Asset extends Eloquent {

public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('BarkCorp\BarkApp\Size');
    }

}
```

Size:

```
<?php namespace BarkCorp\BarkApp;

use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Size extends Eloquent {

}
```

Comment: You need to create a class called `sizes` that extends `Eloquent`.

Comment: Could you show an example , this isnt in the docs.

Comment: How does your autoloading work? classmap or PSR-0/4? If you use PSR autoloading, you should ensure your folder and file names are absolutely exact - naming a class correctly but in an incorrect filename will cause a class not found error. Similarly, putting a class with a given namespace in a different namespace's directory does the same. It can be a bit of a nightmare. If you use classmap, make sure you do a `composer dumpautoload` to ensure it's picked up all your classes.

Answer (score 1):

You need models for both and when you use a relationship function, it takes the class name as an argument, not the name of the table.  The function name can be whatever you want so do whatever makes sense to you there.

```
class Size extends Eloquent {

    // This is optional for what you need now but nice to have in case you need it later
    public function asset()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Namespace\Asset');
    }
}

class Asset extends Eloquent {

    public function sizes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Namespace\Size');
    }
}
```

Namespace = the namespace you have on your `Asset` model.

```
$assetSizes = Namespace\Asset::find(1)->sizes;
```

or you can use `use` so you don't need to add the namespace each time you want to use `Asset`.

```
use Namespace;
$assetSizes = Asset::find(1)->sizes;
```

Or you can use dependency injection.

```
public function __construct(Namespace\Asset $asset)
{
    $this->asset = $asset;
}

$assetSize = $this->asset->find(1)->sizes;
```

Comment: Thanks but this still fails for me. Could namespacing my classes cause an issue?

Comment: If you're using namespaces, you need to specify the namespace in your `hasMany` call as well. Of course, the same holds true for other relationship methods (such as `belongsTo`).

Comment: Are you namespacing the models or the controller which is using the models?

Comment: If both models have the same namespace then do I] need  return $this->hasMany('\Size'); i'm referring to the backslash

Comment: I've modified the answer but it might be easier for you to modify your question to include your namespaces.

Comment: I've followed your namespacing suggestion and class still isnt found. I'll update original question with namespacing details.

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dumpautoload` after creating the `Size` class?